# Is it possible to fix failed upgrade using Ubuntu install?

Tags: upgrade

Suppose that I crashed my system during upgrade.
does Ubuntu installation can detect and fix previously installed system?

Comment: depends on the problem. It typically takes longer and is less reliable to try to fix a failed upgrade then it is to do a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to boot, Ubuntu may or may not be able to solve the problem itself, often you yourself need to go investigate. For example:

During the distro upgrade I left my pc for around two hours, then came back with a black screen. I pushed the reset button and ubuntu booted, only showing up several services active. Using CTRL + ALT + F2 I was able to turn the screen in a terminal, logging in with password and username. Then I did apt-get update and apt-get install ubuntu-desktop. This then continued to update / install packages.

So short answer: Maybe. However, if you ever get stuck on something and don't know how to fix it yourself, you can always ask on this site and volunteers will help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall Ubuntu While Keeping Files and Programs
if there’s a problem with your installed Ubuntu system, you should still be able to boot up an Ubuntu live CD or USB drive. Boot to the live media and start installing Ubuntu. Ubuntu should find your existing installation and give you a “Reinstall Ubuntu” option. When you perform a reinstall, the installer will keep all your personal files and settings. It will even keep your installed software packages, if possible. The Reinstall option will wipe away all your system-wide settings and return them to their defaults, but that should fix problems that misconfigured system settings could cause.

Select this option and continue through the process to reinstall Ubuntu on your computer. The installation process will also reinstall the GRUB2 boot loader along with Ubuntu, so it will also fix any GRUB issues.

[image: screenshot]

If you’re worried about losing your files, it’s always a good idea to have backups. You can use the “Try Ubuntu” option on the Ubuntu installation media to access a graphical desktop. From here, open the file manager and access the files stored on your Ubuntu system drive. Connect some sort of external storage — such as a USB flash drive or external hard drive — to the computer and use the graphical file manager to back up your files.

You’ll find the Ubuntu drive under Devices in the sidebar. You’ll find your personal files in your /home/NAME directory for. Be sure to remember your hidden configuration files if you want to back those up, too.

In theory, this shouldn’t be necessary — the Reinstall option shouldn’t erase your files. However, it’s always a good idea to have backup copies of your files. if you don’t, it’s probably a good idea to create that backup before doing anything else. Something could always go wrong.

Comment: thanks! but it freezed , I tried twice. I'll go for installing alongside.